# NPOI-Styling merged cell

Tags: npoi

I want to chenge ForegroundColor and set text in center at merged cell.

Is it possible to do that by NPOI?

This is my table:
[image]

I know how to set border.But I cant find resources about change merged cell style.

Can someone please give me some tips or help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Row you'll have to set individually like this

```
XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet)workbook.CreateSheet("Template");
XSSFCellStyle headerStyle = (XSSFCellStyle)workbook.CreateCellStyle();
headerStyle.WrapText = true;
headerStyle.FillForegroundColor = IndexedColors.LightBlue.Index;
headerStyle.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
var row = sheet.CreateRow(0);
row.Cells[YourheaderIndex].CellStyle = headerStyle;
```

For columns you can set the style like

```
XSSFCellStyle defaultStyle = (XSSFCellStyle)workbook.CreateCellStyle();
defaultStyle.WrapText = true;
defaultStyle.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
defaultStyle.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
sheet.SetDefaultColumnStyle(YourheaderIndex, defaultStyle);
```

To apply style to merged cell you can try this approach , code is untested though but it will give good idea for available methods in NPOI

```
int mergedRegions = sheet.NumMergedRegions;
for (int regions = 0; regions < mergedRegions; regions++)
{
    CellRangeAddress mergedRegionIndex = sheet.GetMergedRegion(regions);

    for (int currentRegion = mergedRegionIndex.FirstRow; currentRegion < mergedRegionIndex.LastRow; currentRegion++)
    {
        var currentRow = sheet.GetRow(currentRegion);

        for (int currentCell = mergedRegionIndex.FirstColumn; currentCell < mergedRegionIndex.LastColumn; currentCell++)
        {
            // sheet.SetDefaultColumnStyle(i, mandatoryCellStyle);
            currentRow.Cells[currentCell].CellStyle = headerStyle;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean set cell style individually then NPOI will automatically set merged cell style as individual cell style when i merge cells togather?

Comment: Thanks! After I try your code I found 'VerticalAlignment.Center' isnt working. I tried 'VerticalAlignment.Top' and 'HorizontalAlignment.Center' it work properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
  var cra = new NPOI.SS.Util.CellRangeAddress(rowNum, rowNum + 6, 2, 5);
            excelSheet.AddMergedRegion(cra);          
            RegionUtil.SetBorderBottom(1, cra, excelSheet, workbook);//Bottom border  
            RegionUtil.SetBorderLeft(1, cra, excelSheet, workbook);//Left border  
            RegionUtil.SetBorderRight(1, cra, excelSheet, workbook);//Right border  
            RegionUtil.SetBorderTop(1, cra, excelSheet, workbook);
```